# jquery word count and mvc csharp

Tags: jquery

I am coding in c# MVC4.

In my create.cshtml

I have this code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My wonderful creation";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
    var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
    if (words > 100) 
    {
      var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 100).join(" ");
      $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
    }    
  });
}); 
</script>


 <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.mywonderful, new { @id = "word_count" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mywonderful)
        </div>
```

this doesn't work. when i view source, the code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
    var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
    if (words > 100) 
    {
      var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 100).join(" ");
      $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
    }    
  });
}); 
</script>


<div class="editor-field">
            <textarea  id="word_count" name="mywonderful" rows="2" cols="20">
</textarea>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="mywonderful" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

How do I get the word count and validation to work in c# mvc. This is very easy to do in php however, c# mvc is a different story.

I ended up using plain old javascript so that i can use the same code for several textareas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maxWords = 100;
    function limitLengthInWords(field)
    {
        var value = field.value,
            wordCount = value.split(/\S+/).length - 1,
            re = new RegExp("^\\s*\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){0," + (maxWords - 1) + "}");
        if (wordCount >= maxWords)
        {
            field.value = value.match(re);
        }
        document.getElementById('description_count').innerHTML = maxWords - wordCount;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: well, if you see your source code, your making references to jquery functions before calling jquery-1.9.1.js... You should probably put the

Comment: I moved my script to the bottom, and it still didn't work. the glory of c# mvc4

Comment: *"this doesn't work"* doesn't really describe your problem enough for us to help you. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: its actually working, with the exception that I am not seeing the red mvc validation warning. Plus, it looks like i can't use the same function twice. when i tried to use it again with another textarea, it didn't work. only worked for one text area, any suggestions?

Comment: @crush it is, look at the edits i made.

Comment: Okay, well you need to trigger validation somewhere in your keyup function I believe. I despise the jQuery validation stuff though, and never use it, so it's time for me to leave this conversation now that we are at the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have loaded jquery lib after using it!so you can move your top script to the bottom or load the jquery lib at the top

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
    var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
    if (words > 100) 
    {
      var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 100).join(" ");
      $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
    }    
  });
}); 
</script>
```

and

you are checking the textarea so you need to check the innerHtml not the value

```
var words = $(this).html().match(/\S+/g).length;
```

Comment: That's probably because the default MVC4 template puts the jquery bundle at the bottom of the body. He will need to move it manually in the _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: @Crush you are correct. so i then moved my script at the bottom, and it still didn't work.

Comment: @Menew Can you define "didn't work". Is the keyup function getting called at all?

Comment: its actually working, with the exception that I am not seeing the red mvc validation warning. Plus, it looks like i can't use the same function twice. when i tried to use it again with another textarea, it didn't work. only worked for one text area, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with C# or MVC - you are including jQuery *after* you are using jQuery code. When you have any unexpected behaviour, the first thing you check should be the console. You would have seen `$ is undefined` as your first clue for this problem. To fix, try this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
            var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
            if (words > 100)  {
                var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 100).join(" ");
                $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
            }    
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? 'It didn't work' isn't enough information for someone to help you effectively.

Comment: my bad, its working. however, i can't get the validation text to show. do you know how? I also realized I can't used the same code for different text areas?